# Manually specify suggested formula google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Here is how my sheet looks like:

- Column `A:A` includes a series of timestamps.
- for every cell $X`N` where X is between B-K and `N` is a number it's value is either empty or equal to $A`N`-$A`(N-1)`

Many times when I click on a new cell and press `=`, I get the formula I need suggested to me and I can just press enter to fill it, this happens on the columns that already have many sells filled, but when I press `=` on a sell of a column that has only a few sells filled I don't get the formula suggested to me.

Is there any way to make a default formula so whenever I click on a sell in those columns I get that formula filled in or at least when I press `=` I get it suggested to me?

Comment: Hey, can you share a dummy sheet ?

Comment: You should be aware that sharing your spreadsheet will unavoidably expose your email address.

Comment: @Tedinoz thank you so much!

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Just let me say that this still means that you need to supply information to better explain your data, how it is laid out, what you are trying to achieve, etc. Like `_it's value is either empty or equal to $AN-$A(N-1)_` is pretty vague and could be helped by including a screenshot. `_ I get the formula I need suggested to me_` And you need to explain what they formula might be. You also have an obligation to do your own research. Would you please edit your question to describe the research that you did before you posted this question.